# Shared internet to network bridge slows receive on win10

Tags: windows-10, networking, bridge

As soon as internet connection is shared to network bridge, receive is slowed down by 70-90MB/s. Send is unaffected.

[unshared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEEOO.png)

[shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81bG.png)

On 1809 and on 20h2 its 10-20MB/s faster. Latest and oldest drivers for eths.

How does this make sense?

Comment: have you try to install the latest update of windows?

Comment: Yes, on version 20h2 its 10-20mb faster.